# SQS triggering Lambda never sends more than one message in Records

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have the following situation

- "Lambda 1" writes messages to "SQS 1"
- "Lambda 2" has concurrency set to 1 and attached trigger of "SQS 1" with batch size set to 5
- "Lambda 2" finishes after 5 seconds for every call
- I am running my test case by sending 15 messages at the same time

The issue I am having is actually that "Lambda 2" always receive an event with a single message under Records property even at the moment there are multiple messages available (and batch size is 5).
Per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) it should send more (even there is no guaranty) messages under Records property.

Lambda code that receives a message:

```
function timeout(ms, event) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        return setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Received time', new Date());
            console.log('Received event', event);
            resolve()
        }, ms)
    });
}

const handler = async (event) => {
    console.log('Start')
    const records = event.Records;
    for(let record of records) {
       await timeout(5000, record)
    }
    console.log('End')
};

exports.handler = handler;
```

Comment: Can you post the Lambda 2 code for receiving the message?

Comment: @hephalump I have updated question with receiving lambda code